# Binding input to output type in function specification

Tags: elixir

I am currently trying to teach myself how to write [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/) programs.
I've started wondering if there was a way to bind the output type of a function to the type of the input parameters. I'm used to doing stuff like:

```
public virtual T Foo<T>(List<T> bar)
```

I'd like if there is a way similar to this in the sense of:

```
@spec foo(t) :: t
def foo(bar), do: baz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always seen it as

```rb
@spec foo(bar) :: bar when bar: any()
```

reserving `t()` for when the module has an associated type.

See [the typespec docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#defining-a-specification)